# Drop-down list in Ember;

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Is there a way where I can access the selected item in drop down list in ember via controller? Give me a short example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would highly suggest using [ember-power-select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/) as drop down instead of going with html `select`.

Comment: Yeap, +1 for [ember-power-select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a drop down list by using HTML `<select>`:

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  options: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],

  selectedColor: null
});
```

Template:

```
Pick your favourite color:

<br/>

<select onchange={{action (mut selectedColor) value='target.value'}}>
{{#each options as |option|}}
    <option value={{option}}>{{option}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>

<br/><br/>

Your favourite color is: <b>{{selectedColor}}</b>
```

[Live demo.](https://ember-twiddle.com/4129f96a2b36322f74c6d8fa429a2819?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck! :)